# Start Windows Application whenever Windows is Started

Tags: windows, boot, services

Is there anyway to start a windows application whenever windows is started ( i.e., when the OS loads but before I log in)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run it as a Windows Service. The easiest way to do this is to install it via [SrvAny](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) (it's in the resource kit). Microsoft KB Article [KB137890](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) explains how to do it.

Another option, though not free, is to use a third-party tool like [FireDaemon](http://www.firedaemon.com/) to handle creating and monitoring the service.

Comment: Here's a similar walk-through with pictures: http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=197

Answer (score 2):

On recent versions of Windows (read: Vista and higher) you can also use the Task Scheduler to do this. You simply need to set up a task using "On startup" as trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Only if it's installed as a service.  Otherwise it has to start in an interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to run it as a [Windows Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service).